# How to sign in as google or facebook using rest api not using firebase in Flutter

Tags: laravel, api, rest, flutter

I have a scenario where I have to sign in as google and Facebook using rest API(laravel) in a flutter. I don't know How it can be done. Is it possible or not? Please provide me some guidelines

Comment: To sign in with Google/Facebook, you need to use a process called OAuth with google and facebook. This guide might help: https://dev.to/risafj/beginner-s-guide-to-oauth-understanding-access-tokens-and-authorization-codes-2988

Answer (score 2):

My favorite Laravel login authentication is: Laravel Socialite

See here:
https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-socialite

This one will work with Laravel 7/8 versions.

Answer (score 2):

The process would involve making use of another package. This works using a 2 legged Oauth approach.

1. Set up the Facebook/Google SDK on Flutter. You will need this for the first part.
2. Use the socialite library to exchange the token you get from the OAuth step on the client side (Flutter) to the server side.
3. You can then retrieve the owners information including the email.
4. If the email is already on your server then you can trust they are who they are and log them in (return an access token as though they logged in using username and password)
5. If they are not on you database already, you can return some information back to the client and ask them to complete their registration or you can trust that they are a legitimate user and register them silently.

Comment: I just need to add another consideration for the last point. If you are going to register a user silently, ensure you are not checking on email alone.